# how to read values from string in c at vs

Tags: c, string, visual-studio, pointers

My program's goal is to read a string and if the last character is 'o' return 1, else return 2.

I think I located the problem which is at the while loop which reads the string.

Here is the code below.

```
int get_gender(char* noun);
int main() 
{
    char* noun = "ragazzo";
    printf("%d", get_gender(noun));
    return 0;
}

int get_gender(char* noun) 
{
    int word_length = 0;
    while (*noun)
        word_length++;
    if (*(noun + word_length - 1) == 'o')
        return 1;
    return 2;
}
```

When I start the program it doesn't print anything on the screen.

I will appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Hint: your while loop runs forever, because `*noun` never changes.

Comment: Hint: replace `*(noun + word_length - 1)` with `noun[word_length - 1]`. It's more readable and it's the way it is normally done. Other hint: you might want to learn about the `strlen` function.

Comment: Consider dereferencing (noun + word_length -1) in the while loop condition, instead of just noun which always points to first letter.

Comment: `str[ strlen(str) ]` gives you the memory location of the null terminator and therefore `str[ strlen(str)-1 ]` gives you the last character in the string. Take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Change your get_gender function like below :

```
int get_gender(char* noun)
{
   if(null != noun)
   {
       return (noun[strlen(noun)-1] == 'o' ? 1 : 2 ) ;
   }
}
```